# Can 2 identical square combine into a larger square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I mean can twice the  square of an integer be equal to another perfect square?

Comment: If by "number", you mean "integer" (or possibly "natural number"), the answer is either "no" or "yes, but only the trivial case $0^2=0^2+0^2$". This question is linked to the *irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$*.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ satisfy

$$2k^2 = n^2 \tag1$$

then we have $($excluding the trivial case of $k=n=0)$

$$2k^2 = n^2 \implies 2=\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2\implies\sqrt{2} = \frac{k}{n}
$$

This is a contradiction, as the square root of $2$ is irrational. Therefore, no $k, n\in\{\mathbb{N}\backslash 0\}$ exist that satisfy $(1)$.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging the trivial case, and explicitly making the link to the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative way using the Fundamental theorem of Arithemetic:
let $m^2=2n^2$. Then represent $n^2 = 2^{a_1}3^{a_2}\cdots$ in canonical form. Then, $a_1$ is even. Which means, $m^2 = 2^{a_1+1}3^{a_2}\cdots$. As, $a_1+1$ is odd, we have a contradiction.
Note: This method, too uses the irrationality of $\sqrt2$, but implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

No. Because $a^2 + a^2 = 2a^2$.

But $\sqrt{2a^2}=\sqrt2\times a$.

Since $\sqrt2$ is irrational. $\sqrt2\times a$ is not an integer. $2a^2$ can never be perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

Let you have number n.

Then twice its square = $2n^2$ = 2 * n * n.

As you can see 2 as its one factor and 2 is not a perfect square. So twice the square of a number is not square.

Comment: When you are down voting please comment the reason so that one can know the reason and try to improve.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO.

As well mentioned in other answers, the sum of two squares will be $n^2+n^2=(\sqrt{2}n)^2$ which is not considered a perfect square as definition of [perfect square](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYgoekn57RAhXFsY8KHeEJCCYQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSquare_number&usg=AFQjCNFuix3b0jF3DMOmvr_kzO4qZrWEWw) is that :

> An integer that is square of another integer.

Since $(\sqrt{2}n)$ is not an integer, so  $(\sqrt{2}n)^2$ is not a perfect square.